# Prove that $\ln(i) = i(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, pi

The following is a trial proof in which I try to establish a link between $\pi$ and $\ln(i)$.
I want your hints if it is false.

---

We can use Euler's formula to relate $e^{i\pi}$ to $\cos(\pi)$ and $\sin(\pi)$, and the definition of the natural logarithm to relate $\ln(i)$ to its real and imaginary parts. Then we can combine these to obtain a formula that relates $e^{i\pi}$ and $\ln(i)$.

Euler's formula states that $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ for any real number theta. So, if we let $\theta = \pi$, we have:

$e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)$

Now, $\cos(\pi) = -1$ and $\sin(\pi) = 0$, so we have:

$e^{i\pi} = -1$

Next, we use the definition of the natural logarithm to write $\ln(i)$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts. Recall that for any complex number $z = x + iy$ (where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers), we have:

$\ln(z) = \ln(|z|) + i\arg(z)$

where $|z|$ is the modulus (or absolute value) of $z$, and $\arg(z)$ is the argument (or angle) of $z$.

For $i$, we have $|i| = 1$ and $\arg(i) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (since $i$ is the complex number that lies on the positive imaginary axis). So we have:

$\ln(i) = \ln(1) + i\frac{\pi}{2}$

Simplifying, we have:

$$\ln(i) = i\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: No, there are infinitely many possible arguments.

Comment: The first half of your post has nothing to do with the second half, since you do not use your calculation of $e^{i \pi}$ for $\log(i)$ (though the results are indeed rated). Your calculation itself is fine except that you didn't specify a branch cut. Assuming you choose a branch cut that $\arg(i) = \pi/2$ your argument works, eg the standard branch.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asPo4xsxFlM&t=1s)

Comment: Well, the *principal* value of log(i) is certainly pi i/2 since $e^{\pi i\over 2}=i$

Comment: The claim in your title verges on being false. If you had said "The square root of 4 is 2", then I'd expect you to deal with -2, and include some discussion of different branches of the square root function. You should do the same for arg(z) here.